# MySQL: Incorrect query or bad structuring of the database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

this is estructure of mi database for movie online store:

[image]

And these are the sql statements for its creation

**movies**

```
CREATE TABLE `movies` (
  `id_movie` varchar(4) NOT NULL default '',
  `nom_movie` varchar(30) default NULL,
  `detall_movie` text,
  `precio_movie` varchar(6) default NULL,
  `img_rut_movie` varchar(50) default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_movie`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**generos**

```
CREATE TABLE `genres` (
  `id_genre` varchar(3) collate utf8_bin NOT NULL default '',
  `nom_genre` varchar(20) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id_genero`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

**movie_genero**

```
CREATE TABLE `movie_genre` (
  `id_movie` varchar(4) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  `id_genre` varchar(3) collate utf8_bin default NULL,
  FOREIGN KEY(id_movie) REFERENCES movies(id_movie),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_genero) REFERENCES generos(id_genero)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

And e.g. , I want to show the movies that belong to the genre "Action":

```
SELECT nom_movie FROM movies, genres, movie_genre WHERE genres.nom_genre = 'action';
```

But it shows more than 1200 results!!, ie repeats the 36 movies that are hosted in the movies table 36 times.

I hope you can help!!

Comment: You are mising the conditions to join the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even with a Distinct that's an inefficient query. I'd suggest a proper inner join. This should do it:

```
select 
  m.nom_movie 
FROM 
  movies 
inner join
  movie_genre mg
on
  m.id_movie=mg.id_movie 
inner join 
  genres g 
on 
  mg.id_genre=g.id_genre 
where 
  g.nom_genre = 'action';
```

Comment: In his schema there is no `id_movie` in `genres`, so you'd have to join `genres` and `movie_genres` by `id_genre`.

Comment: Nice.... worked for me :).. I had forgotten the union between the tables, all answers display same results but ur structure is better!!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT movies.nom_movie
FROM movies, genres, movie_genre
WHERE
    movies.id_movie = movie_genre.id_movie
    and movie_genre.id_genre = genre.id_genre
    and genres.nom_genre = 'action';
```

Comment: Thanks man, ur solution worked for me :) ,but the sentence is more structured @llion

Answer (score 1):

The structure is perfect, just use this query.

```
 SELECT nom_movie FROM movies, genres, movie_genre WHERE genres.nom_genre = 'action' AND genres.id_genre= movie_genre.id_genre AND movie_genre.id_movie=movies.id_movie ;
```

Comment: Thanks man, ur solution worked for me :) but the sentence is more structured @llion

Comment: You are welcome, I gave you the inline code bc it's easier to use when programming. @llion's is Clearer though +1